# Generating a Text Field from List Options

Tags: javascript, html, text, filter

I am creating a little app to help me be more productive at work. I currently have some html/js code where I have a ul with a search filter and when I click an option it creates a new tab with the associated text.

Optimally, I would like the end result to be a single popup text field generated from multiple options in the list.

Ex. 
List Option 1 - Abnormal conditions
List Option 2 - Water contamination
List Option 3 - Monitor closely

Each of these list options would have about a paragraph of text associated with them. When I click on multiple options, it would create a pop-up text field containing those three paragraphs added together in order.

Could you guys give me some pointers on how I might accomplish this?

```
<li><a href="#" target="_blank">Abnormal conditions</a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_blank">Water contamination</a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_blank">Monitor closely</a></li>
```

As you can see, this is currently just opening a new tab. I would like to change the code to have it take the paragraph associated with each option and add them all together in a single pop-up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Water Contamination</title> </head> <body> <p><br>Some text.<br></p> </body> </html>
```

Here is an example of the sort of page I am linking to.

Comment: Please show an HTML example of the paragraphs and the relations to the links

Comment: Please update the QUESTION

Answer (score 1):

the new tab is a new window. you'll need somewhere to store the data to, then be able to recall it from the other page.

this can get complicated.

Wix, has a cool front end, free to use, and allows you to store variables in a session. you could use this functionality to store data in the session for short term, or even stick it into a database for recall later.

if you need a pop-up window, i would recommend using a modal window, as this wont take you to another page so you wont have to save and load the data.

here are some resources. let me know if you have any other questions

https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-storage.html
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be a pop-up window, if the text gets compiled onto a new tab, that would be fine. Mainly I would just like the ability to select multiple entries in a list and have associated text get added together and presented some place.

Comment: yeah a new tab IS pretty much the same as a new window. Your browser just organizes it in a different way.

You should check out that modal window example and see if its what you want